Rebus UseSqlServerInLeaseMode Obsolete
I have some code that is using the Obsolete version of UseSqlServerInLeaseMode when adding a Rebus service to my app.
The obsolete version (below) has several parameters, all (but the last) of which are in use in my code.
public static void UseSqlServerInLeaseMode(
    this StandardConfigurer<ITransport> configurer,
    string connectionString,
    string inputQueueName,
    TimeSpan? leaseInterval = null,
    TimeSpan? leaseTolerance = null,
    bool automaticallyRenewLeases = false,
    TimeSpan? leaseAutoRenewInterval = null,
    Func<string> leasedByFactory = null,
    bool enlistInAmbientTransaction = false,
    bool ensureTablesAreCreated = true
)


The recommended version I should be using is:
public static SqlServerLeaseTransportOptions UseSqlServerInLeaseMode(
    this StandardConfigurer<ITransport> configurer,
    SqlServerLeaseTransportOptions transportOptions,
    string inputQueueName
)

I'm really not clear how I should use this new version, most of the parameters in the new classes seem to be readonly and every variation I have tried so far will not compile.
Does someone have a code snippet showing how I remove this obsolete code?
Many thanks!

The trick is to use the various Set... functions within SqlServerLeaseTransportOptions
So to convert from this:
x.UseSqlServerInLeaseMode(
    connectionString,
    inputQueueName,
    leaseInterval,
    leaseTolerance,
    automaticallyRenewLeases,
    leaseAutoRenewInterval,
    leasedByFactory,
    enlistInAmbientTransaction,
    ensureTablesAreCreated,
)

It should look like this:
SqlServerLeaseTransportOptions transportOptions = new(connectionString, enlistInAmbientTransaction);
transportOptions.SetLeaseInterval(leaseInterval);
transportOptions.SetLeaseTolerance(leaseTolerance);
transportOptions.SetAutomaticLeaseRenewal(automaticallyRenewLeases, leaseAutoRenewInterval);
transportOptions.SetLeasedByFactory(leasedByFactory);
transportOptions.SetEnsureTablesAreCreated(ensureTablesAreCreated);

x.UseSqlServerInLeaseMode(
    transportOptions,
    inputQueueName
);

